# Pause button only scrambling audio for short period

Tags: java, android

I'm fairly new to Java and have been developing an app to stream live audio from the Internet. I've got everything working except for the pause button. All it does for now is scramble the audio for a short period.  I'm guessing it has something to do with where `mediaPlayer.pause()` is called, but I may be wrong. Thank you for your time and response.

```
package com.example.jacob.wutk;

import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

import java.io.IOException;

public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    /** Called when the user touches the button */

    public void playPauseMusic (View playPause) throws IOException {
        String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; // your URL here
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

        ImageButton imb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playPause);

        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
            mediaPlayer.pause();
            return;
        } else {
            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause1);
        }

        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this code :

```
com.example.jacob.wutk;

        import android.media.AudioManager;
        import android.media.MediaPlayer;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.widget.ImageButton;

        import java.io.IOException;

public class radio extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    private boolean isMediaPlayerStarted = false;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_radio);
        setMediaPlayer();
    }

    public void setMediaPlayer() {
        try {
            mediPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            String url = "http://streamer.cci.utk.edu:8000/wutk-vorbis"; 

            ImageButton imb = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.playPause);

            imb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!isMediaPlayerStarte) {
                        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                        isMediaPlayerStarted = true;
                    } else {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.play1);
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        } else {
                            imb.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause1);
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

            mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It works great. I'll accept it, but I do have two requests. 1.) Can you make to where the MediaPlayer doesn't start until playPause is pressed? 2.) I'm new to Java, so can you explain what you did here?

Comment: I edit my question. Now to explain : 
I create one boolean parameter to check if MediaPlayer is prepared (is ready to start), and after we create this ImageButton (imb), we set to it an onClickListener (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) and tell to the listener that, if we aren't prepaid the MediaPlayer, to start prepare it and set the boolean parameter to true (to know that the MediaPlayer is already prepared). And then every time you click the ImageButton (imb), we go in else function (where check if player is paused to start it or to stop it )